# Sorting array of objects does not work

Tags: javascript, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm working with Firebase and need to perform a sort on database items (named 'adsets') once they have completed loading. I add each 'adset' item to the array 'adsets'. Once all of the calculations are done I sort 'adsets' by 'adsetDeviation'. The issue is that this doesn't work at all - the objects in adsets array are not sorted:

```
  function main() {
    ...
   //Irrelvant code ommitted

    var adsets = [];

    //Create promise that resolves once all the calculations are done for all the adsets
    var adsetPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      for (var currentAdsetId in campaign.adsets) {
        loadAdsets(currentAdsetId, adsets);
      }

      //Resolve the promise
      resolve(adsets);

    });

   //Sort and print full adset list
    adsetPromise.then(function(fullList) {
      console.log('by Deviation:');
      // Sort the adsets by Deviation 
      fullList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.adsetDeviation - b.adsetDeviation
      });
      console.log(fullList);
    });
  }

  function loadAdsets(adsetId, adsets) {
    firebase.database().ref('/adsets/' + adsetId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var adset = snapshot.val();

      adset.adsetDeviation = Math.ceil(adset.flight - adset.budget);

      adsets.push(adset);
    });
  }
```

Console prints this:

[image: console]

***Why is this not sorted in adsetDeviation order?***

Comment: shouldn't you put "return" before "a.adsetDeviation - b.adsetDeviation"?

Comment: Also, you are calling `resolve(adsets)` *before* any async code completes.

Comment: Thanks @AymanElTemsahi I put that in but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @nnnnnn I can see what you mean... I'm not sure where to put the resolve...

Comment: I would have `loadAdsets()` return a promise (you can perhaps just add `return` in front of the existing statement in that function, because `.then()` will return a promise), have your other function's loop put all the returned promises into an array, then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises in the array to resolve.

Comment: @nnnnnn it worked! Thank you - you saved me so much time.